# Grouping object string using includes()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object. It looks like below:

```
var records = ["test1 name1", "test2 name2", "test1 name3", "test1 name4"];
```

I would like to group this data by group field and get this object:

```
var obj = [["test1 name1", "test1 name3", "test1 name4"], ["test2 name2"]];
```

How can I group my string object using `includes()` in test word?

Answer (score 0):

Once you use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) then you can reference the first element of the returned array what you can use for grouping the strings into the sub arrays.

Using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const records = ["test1 name1", "test2 name2", "test1 name3", "test1 name4"];

const result = records.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = a.find(e => e[0].split(' ')[0] === c.split(' ')[0]);
  
  if (found) found.push(c);
  else a.push([c]);

  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!